# Referencing JPA project in a JSF project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jpa

I want to create a JSF project with JPA. I am using eclipse juno 4.2 How can I integrate both in one project? 
I read somewhere that keeping JSF and JPA project separately is a good practice, but I don't know how to do this. If I am using two different projects that is for JSF one project and JPA another how do I integrate and make it working depending on each other?

Comment: Reference : http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/JSF_Tutorial

Comment: if you use ant, your IDE should allow you to add a project as a dependency (at least it's possible under netbeans), or add the jpa project jar to the jsf project. if you are using maven, it's possible to include a dependency of a local jar, you'll have to google it. anyway, I've never seen that, I always use one single project.

Comment: they are two different frameworks for two different things. Not sure why should be separated. Anyway you can create 2 projects - 1 for DB (jpa) and second for JSF which include 1st as jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties of the JSF project, add the JPA project as *Deployment Assembly*. This way the JPA project will end up as JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the JSF project, which is exactly what you need after all.

Further you should make sure that you haven't fiddled/messed around in *Build Path*  property in an careless attempt to solve this. If you changed anything there, make absolutely sure that you undo it.